# Finding arbitrary value in joint pmf of discrete random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am learning about probability and have a relatively good understanding of how random variables work. I am a little confused with this question as I have never seen an arbitrary (k value in this case) value in the pmf of two discrete random variables.

> The joint pmf of two discrete random variables X and Y is given by Px,y (*x,y*) = *k(x + 3y)*.
>
> The support of X is *X* = {0,1,2}, whereas the support of Y is *Y* = {0,1,2,3).

The question then continues to ask to find the value of *k*, obtain the pmf's of both X and Y and determine whether they are independent or not.

I am finding it difficult to understand how to find the value of k in the beginning?

Comment: Hint: remember that the sum of a pmf over its support is 1. That is, $\sum_{x=0}^2\sum_{y=0}^3 P_{x,y}(x,y) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the sum of a PMF over its support is $1$. Therefore,
$$1=\sum_{x=0}^2\sum_{y=0}^3 P_{X,Y}(x,y) =k \sum_{x=0}^2\sum_{y=0}^3 (x+3y)=66k,$$ from which we deduce $k=\displaystyle\frac{1}{66}$.

Moreover, notice that \begin{align}
P_X(x) &= P(X=x)\\
&=\sum_{y =0}^3 P(X=x, Y=y) &\textrm{(law of total probablity)}\\
&=\sum_{y =0}^3 P_{XY}(x,y).
\end{align}
Similarly, $P_Y(y)=\sum_{x=0}^2 P_{XY}(x,y)$. Hence,
$$P_Y(y)=\sum_{x=0}^2 P_{XY}(x,y)=\sum_{x=0}^2 \frac{1}{66}(x+3y)=\frac{3y}{22}+\frac{1}{22}$$ and
$$P_X(x)=\sum_{y=0}^3 P_{XY}(x,y)=\sum_{y=0}^3\frac{1}{66}(x+3y)=\frac{2x}{33}+\frac{3}{11}.$$

For independence, recall that $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $P_{X,Y}(x,y)=P_X(x)P_Y(y)$, for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Can I ask how you deduced that the first equation is equal to 66k? how do you get 66?

Comment: @DeclanMorgan Sure, this is just double summation:
\begin{align} \sum_{x=0}^2\sum_{y=0}^3 (x+3y)&=\sum_{x=0}^2\left[(x+0)+(x+3)+(x+6)+(x+9)\right]\\ &= \left[(0+0)+(0+3)+(0+6)+(0+9)\right]+\left[(1+0)+(1+3)+(1+6)+(1+9)\right]+\left[(2+0)+(2+3)+(2+6)+(2+9)\right]\\ &= 18+22+26=66
\end{align}
See, for example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGQMmpTInPU) to see how to compute a double summation.